# How to use conditional in List.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, linq-to-objects

I need to remove items from the HttpSession collection.  In the following code, myList contains the same items as Session.  If there are items in myList/Session that are not in itemsToRemove, they should be deleted from the session collection.

However, I'm not sure what the lambda syntax should look like.  The following isn't correct.

```
myList.ForEach(x => !itemsToRemove.Contains(x) { Session.Remove(x) });
```

Any ideas how I can use a lambda expression to put everything on one line to accomplish this task?

Also, is there a way to avoid creating the intermediate list (myList)?  I'm only doing that because I can't remove items from Session while iterating through it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most naïve way:

```
myList.Where(x => !itemsToRemove.Contains(x)) // LINQ extension method
      .ToList()                                                                 <----
      .ForEach(x => Session.Remove(x));       // List<T> method so this is required |
```

Also you can use this:

```
mystList.Except(itemsToRemove)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => Session.Remove(x));
```

---

But to use `ForEach` the underlying type should be `List<T>` so you need to call `ToList()` first. What causes 1 excess enumeration of the whole collection.

I would do this instead:

```
foreach (var x in mystList.Except(itemsToRemove))
{
    Session.Remove(x)
}
```

This will minimize the number of enumerations.

Comment: Where does .Except come from?  I'm using a List<string> and don't see that.

Comment: @4thSpace: Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: It looks like the Session collection still needs to go into a List<T>?  Hence the two list you are using the "I would do this instead" part?

Comment: @4thSpace: LINQ extensions methods work for `IEnumerable<T>` so it isn't necessary to call `ToList()`. However note that these are "hot" enumerators not yet materialized into memory. It's called "[deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)", need to learn about it when using LINQ.

Comment: @4thSpace It would be more accurate to say that *most* LINQ extensions are for `IEnumerable<T>`. As a collection, HttpSessionState should support the `.OfType<T>()` method, which will give you all the elements of the collection of type T in an `IEnumerable<T>`, which you can then use other LINQ methods with.

Answer (score 0):

First off, abatischev's answer is excellent. It's ideal from both a performance perspective and a readability perspective. If, however, you **really** want to cram all the functionality into one statement (which I don't recommend), you could try the following:

```
Session.OfType<string>()
       .Except(itemsToRemove)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(x => Session.Remove(x));
```

As abatischev metnioned, the `ToList()` call costs you an extra enumeration through the collection, which could have a non-trivial performance impact if the collection has a large number of elements in it. However, it means the `ForEach()` call iterates over a newly created `List<string>`, which fills the role of your `myList` and lets you remove items from the Session (since you're iterating through that temporary list, rather than the Session).

<sub>(Note that I haven't worked with HttpSessionState objects myself, merely looked at their MSDN article. You may need to replace the `string` generic type with something else if strings aren't what HttpSessionState holds.)</sub>